# General /etc/nginx/vhosts/default - how to specify server wide settings?

Tags: configuration, nginx, settings

From what I see if I write in the /etc/nginx/vhosts/default the effect will be server wide contrary to per domain confs. I can't seem to know how to write a rule to redirect from /index.html or /dir/index.html ro / or /dir/ to have server wide effects.

The thing is that running on CentOS makes files in /home/user/public_html and from nginx I can't see the user part to use it in the root directive. I thought of something like this:

```
---
server
{
listen 111.111.111.111:80;           // fake IP
server_name "";                      // this to take in all hosts... ??
root ~^/home/(.*)/public_html;       // this (.*) would contain the user part
rewrite ^(.*/)index.(html|htm) http://$host$1 permanent;
}
---
```

As you can see.. probably.. I'm trying to make that redirect work for all sites without having to manually edit each specific per domain conf file but rather have it in the /etc/nginx/vhosts/default conf file.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Thank you

Comment: server_name ""; -- used for request without Host: header

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<user>.+)\.domain\.com$;

    location / {
        root  /home/$user/public_html;
    }
}
```

Also, you can't use regexes in `root` cause it's a definition not a match.